# Missing labels in matplotlib pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I try to plot a pie chart using Python 3 Matplotlib v2.2.2-4build1 on Ubuntu 18.10. Everything seems to be ok except labels - they are missing. Tried to add it according to official documentation (https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html), tried to use an example from the web (https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-pie-chart/) - same result, no labels.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

headers = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
values = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
sum = sum(values)
labels = []
for v in values:
    labels.append('{:.1f}%'.format(100 * v / sum))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))
wedges, texts = ax.pie(values, labels=labels, textprops=dict(color="w"))
plt.show()
```

Here is what I see - no labels:

[image: Pie chart with no labels]

Tried to use a tuple instead of a list - same thing.

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to make the color of your labels non-white on a white background :)

Also using sum as a variable name overwrites the function, so your're better off choosing something else.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

headers = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
values = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
sumT = sum(values)
labels = []
for v in values:
    labels.append('{:.1f}%'.format(100 * v / sumT))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))
wedges, texts = ax.pie(values, labels=labels, textprops=dict(color="k"))
plt.show()
```

Or if you want the labels to be inside:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

def func(pct, allvals):
    absolute = int(pct/100.*sum(allvals))
    return "{:.1f}%)".format(pct)

headers = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
values = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
sumT = sum(values)
labels = []
for v in values:
    labels.append('{:.1f}%'.format(100 * v / sumT))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))
wedges, texts = ax.pie(values, autopct=lambda pct: func(pct, 
values), textprops=dict(color="w"))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Damn it, so simple :) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

headers = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
values = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
colors=['yellow','blue','red','pink','green']

plt.pie(values,labels=headers,
        colors=colors,autopct='%1.2f%%',
        shadow=True,startangle=90)
plt.title('pie chart')
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Adding the plt.legend() statement before the plt.show() will do the job.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

headers = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
values = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
labels = []
for v in values:
    labels.append('{:.1f}%'.format(100 * v / sum))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))
wedges, texts = ax.pie(values, labels=labels, textprops=dict(color="w"))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I don't need legend, I need labels, it is another thing. See example at https://pythonspot-9329.kxcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/matplotlib_pie.png.webp, no legend there and ["Java", "Ruby", "C++", "Python"] are labels in terms of Matplotlib